# trouble getting info from an array and then inserting it into a db

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a page that I have been working on.  It runs several queries to get existing data from several tables in my DB.  There is a table that shows the result of three queries.  The first query gets the extension and the secret of phones, the 2nd query gets MAC addresses of phones, and finally the third query gets the names of templates for the phones.  The results of the last two queries (with the help of others) are setup as dropdowns in the 3rd and 4th columns of the table created to show the extensions.  This way I can select the MAC of the phone I want to assign to the extension and then the template to make the phone work the way I want.  The whole page is set as a form and I am using $post to the insert page. My goal here is to take the information (array) that is created by the user making their selections and insert ALL the 4 columns of information into a new table, from there I want to create files using that information to setup the phones.  Here is the code I have for now.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "cacti") or die ('Error       connecting to mysql' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("cqadmin");

$sql2 = "SELECT extension, secret from extensions;";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='3'>
    <tr>
        <th>Extension #</th>
        <th>Secret</th>
        <th>MAC Address</th>
        <th>Template</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $sql = "SELECT id , mac FROM phones order by mac;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql1 = "SELECT id , templatename FROM templates order by templatename;";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['secret'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <select name='phone'>";
    while($rowA = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $rowA['id'] . '">' . $rowA['mac'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<td><select name='template'>";
    while($rowB = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $rowB['id'] . '">' . $rowB['templatename'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>


<input type="submit" value="Submit your selections">
</body>
</html>

    And my insert page
        <?php
    echo "You got here";
    //***********Get the Assignment information *************
    $values = array_values($_POST);
    print_r($values);
    ?>
```

The resulting print shows this

Array ( [0] => 324 [1] => 24 )

Looking at my db table 324 is the index id of the last phone scanned and in the template table 24 is the last template created, No info on the extension or the secret.
I think I am close but I do not know where to go from here.

PS.  I know I need to use mysqli or pdo,  not sure how to change over yet.

Comment: Every value of `_POST[phone]` is overwritten by the next one. Same for `template`. If you need all values on submit - change names to `'template[]'` and `'phone[]'`.

Comment: If you want to access your data with the column names as keys you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: I tried to change the extension nd secret to:echo "<td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['secret'] . "</td>";

Comment: page wouldn't load

Comment: Following u_mulders' post I now am getting info in the array and into the insert page.  I still need to figure out how to get the extension and secret into the array.